# Event click not working. can you solve it for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to delete an element when I click it

HTML

```
<span id="portoDeleteFIle_${id}" class="deleteFile" title="Delete">+</span>

//${id} is number and < 99
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("span[id^='portoDeleteFIle_']").click(function(e) {
      id = e.currentTarget.attributes.id.value.replace("portoDeleteFIle_", "");
      console.log(id);
});
</script>
```

Comment: need a jsfiddle. and what error do you get in console?

Comment: I would suggest you give more information as to what you're trying to achieve. Post title says something else and content says something else, also there's no code in your example to actually delete an html element.

Comment: it simply not working.I'm just trying to get it to run js

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/vfdej725/).   Open the browser console (F12, select console) and check for any errors, such as `jQuery not defined`.   *If* your `span` is generated *after* your js runs, then either: 1) wrap the click event in doc.ready (see [learn jquery doc ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or 2) use event delegation (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("span[id^='portoDeleteFIle_']").click(function(e) {
      id = e.currentTarget.attributes.id.value.replace("portoDeleteFIle_", "");
      console.log(id);
});
```

There was missing **)** in your code.

Comment: use a text edtior with some javascript extensions and errors like this will be highlighted, like vscode